# Using Maven Invoker, how can I get the log messages

Tags: maven, maven-invoker-plugin

Is there any way to programmatically inspect process log messages using the Maven Invoker framework?

I am using that framework to execute some integration tests against an embedded server (Jetty), and I need to inspect the logs to know when the server startup has completed. Our Jetty is using Slf4j for logging.

I tried creating my own InvokerLogger attached to a ByteArrayOutputStream, but that just produced an empty string.

Is there any way to programmatically grab the log messages?

Comment: does running the 2 goals `maven jetty:run integration-test` work?

Comment: It never gets to the integration tests. jetty:run is hogging the flow control

Comment: There is a wait plugin for maven: [MavenWaitPlugin](https://code.google.com/p/agimatec-maven-plugins/wiki/MavenWaitPlugin)